# Knowing $X$ and $Y|X$, determine $Y$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables where

$X$ is binomially distributed with $n$ trials and success probability $p_1$

$Y | X = x$ is binomially distributed with $n$ trials and success probability $p_2$

Determine the marginal distribution of $Y$.

Its been a while since I've played around with conditional distributions, any help?

Comment: You miscopied: most probably, $Y | X = x$ is binomially distributed with $x$ trials and success probability $p_2$ (not with $n$ trials and success probability $p_2$). As a result the answer below does not apply.

Comment: @Did I did not miscopy. This is the question. Could you not downvote a perfectly legitimate question?

Comment: How do you know who votes what? If you have a recipe, please explain it, I am interested. "I did not miscopy. This is the question." OK, this is very surprising but if you say so, I guess you had the time to check the source in the lapse of approximately 2 minutes between my comment and yours?

Comment: @Did Since I had the book open, I did just that yes. This was the first question and the question you posed was asked at a later point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(Y=y)=\sum_xP(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)\\$$

However check that The distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is independent of $x$.

So the marginal of $Y$ will be $Bin(n,p_2)$

Comment: Because $\sum_x P(X=x) = 1$ right?

Comment: @Neutronic Absolutely

Comment: @Neutronic May I know the reason for you not accepting my answer? Any doubts?

Comment: There was a timer when I tried and forgot :)